# Check object for property

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have an object

```
var person = [{
  name: 'true',
  city: 'false'
}]
```

and I have a predefined list of property names I would like to check against

```
let props = ['name', 'address']
```

How can I use lodash [_.includes](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#includes) to check?

I've tried variations of the following to no avail, all return false

```
_.includes(person, [props]);
_.includes(person, 'name');
_.includes([person], 'name');
```

Comment: `person` is an array

Comment: @ASDFGerte still get false

Comment: You simply can't do it with `_.includes`. You can use `_.has` on an object if an object possesses a property. However, I'm not even sure if that answers your question, as I'm not sure what check do you want to do.

Comment: @vlaz sorry for confusion. just wanted to check the values of all the properties in person1, whether true or false, and take all the trues and put them in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- UPDATED --
Given your updated description, this is what the code will look like to get the results you desire.

```js
const person = [{
  name: 'true',
  city: 'false'
}];
const props = ['name','address'];
let found = [];

Object.keys(person[0]).forEach(key => {
    if(props.includes(key)) found.push(key)
});

// Found now contains ['name']
```

Comment: sorry for confusion. just wanted to check the values of all the properties in person1, whether true or false, and take all the trues and put them in an array. so in my example i should get back an array with [name], because it was found and is true.

Comment: person is an array, not an object. Do you plan to insert multiple objects within the person array?